# I believe jquery increment is causing the wrong number to be inserted into the database

Tags: php, jquery

I want the correct question number to be displayed in the database table but problem is that it is displaying incorrect question numbers by +1.

Lets say I have 4 rows and I used file input in row 2 and row 4 to upload the files, then it means the question numbers should be 2 and 4 meaning the table should look like this below:

```
ImageId    SessionId  QuestionId
01               AAA        2
02               AAA        4
```

But instead it has got the question number wrong by only plus 1 meaning it is displaying it like this:

```
ImageId    SessionId  QuestionId
01               AAA        3
02               AAA        5
```

I believe the problem is that I am not inncrementing the question numbers correctly. Can anybody see what I am doing incorrectly in my code below that it is inserting the wrong question numbers?

Below is the code:

```
var qnum = 1; //question number starts at 1
var qremain = <?php echo (int)$_SESSION['textQuestion']; ?>; //the full number of questions

var $qid = $("<td class='qid'></td>" ).text(qnum);
var $image = $("<td class='image'></td>");    

var $fileImage = $("<form action='imageupload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target' onsubmit='return imageClickHandler(this);' class='imageuploadform' >" + 
        "Image File: <input name='fileImage' type='file' class='fileImage' /></label><br/><br/><label class='imagelbl'>" + 
    "<input type='submit' name='submitImageBtn' class='sbtnimage' value='Upload' /></label>" + 
    "<label><input type='button' name='imageClear' class='imageClear' value='Clear File'/></label>" +
    "</p></form>"); 


$tr.append($qid);
$tr.append($image);

$('.num_questions').each( function() {

    var $this = $(this);

    var $questionNumber = $("<input type='hidden' class='num_questionsRow'>").attr('name',$this.attr('name')+"[]")
                   .attr('value',$this.val());

    $qid.append($questionNumber);                             

    ++qnum;
    $(".questionNum").text(qnum);
    $(".num_questions").val(qnum);

    --qremain;
    $(".questionRemain").text(qremain);
});
```

How the `$('.num_questions').each( function() {` work is like this:

- When user opens page, qnum (question number) starts with '1' at the top
- When user appends a table row, then it will take question number '1' from the top and display it within the added row and the qnum (question number) at the top increments so that it now states 2
- When user appends another row, it will take question number '2' from the top and display it within the added row and the qnum (question number) at the top increments so it now displays 3.
- And so and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not start with `var qnum = 0;`? Most incremental functions do!

**EDIT**

You're incrementing `++qnum` before using `.text` and `.val` to display the value in the row. Try incrementing afterwards. Your each function would end with:

```
$(".questionNum").text(qnum);
$(".num_questions").val(qnum);
++qnum;

$(".questionRemain").text(qremain);
--qremain;
```

Comment: Because if I start with qnum = 0, then when I append the first row in the table, it states for question number 0, which is incorrect it should be 1, first row represents question 1, second row represents question 2 and so on. If I do qnum = 0 then first row willbe question 0, second row will be question 1 and so on, which is incorrect

Comment: Try changing the order of your incrementation and display – see updated answer.

Comment: does var qnum still be 1 or 0?

Comment: Why not give both a whirl? I was assuming you wanted to leave it at 1 to begin with, per your first comment.

Comment: Ok if I keep qnum to 1, the the question numbers within the the appended rows are correct (if I have 3 rows then it will state 1,2 and 3 for the 3 rows) but the database still inserts the wrong numbers by plus 1. If I set qnum = 0, then the database inserts the correct question numbers but the question numbers within the appended rows are incorrect (if there are 3 rows instead of stating 1,2,3, it states 0,1,2)

Comment: IT is ok, figured it out, I kept the code the same but incuded an extra variable `numq - 0` and use qnum to deal with outputting correct questino numbers in appended rows and use numq to insert correct numbers in database. Thanks both of you for your help :)